# Can someone explain "Noble Eightfold Path" in depth?

Tags: eightfold-path

This is the common answer:

Right view,
Right intention,
Right speech,
Right action,
Right livelihood,
Right effort,
Right mindfulness,
Right concentration,

But what is e.g. the Right view?

How do i know my efforts are correct?

Can someone explain these 8 in day to day practice?

Comment: maybe you should ask 8 separate questions? I'm afraid this answer may get rather long...

Comment: Since the 8 fold path is basically *buddhism*, you're looking for an answer that encapsulates the whole thing. I'd start [here](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/bodhi/waytoend.html) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_Eightfold_Path) and then ask specific questions to clarify.

Comment: Check out Gunaratana's Eight Mindful Steps to Happiness.  It's a nice, practical introduction to the eightfold path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The whole of the Noble Path can be summarized as the action, speech, effort, intent etc. **coming from the two kinds of thoughts** as explained in MN 19:

> Bhikkhus, before my enlightenment, while I was still only an unenlightened Bodhisatta, it occurred to me: ‘Suppose that I divide my thoughts into two classes [-- useful and harmful].
> ...
> As I abided thus, diligent, ardent, and resolute, a thought of [the harmful kind] arose in me. I understood thus: ‘This thought [of the harmful kind] has arisen in me. This leads to my own affliction, to others’ affliction, and to the affliction of both; it obstructs wisdom, causes difficulties, and leads away from Nibbāna.’
> ...
> As I abided thus, diligent, ardent, and resolute, a thought of [the useful kind] arose in me. I understood thus: ‘This thought of [the useful kind] has arisen in me. This does not lead to my own affliction, or to others’ affliction, or to the affliction of both; it aids wisdom, does not cause difficulties, and leads to Nibbāna.

Briefly, my personal opinions / commentary.

**Arya marga.** Here, "arya" ("noble") stands for "advanced person" and "marga" ("path") stands for "training method". Together it means "The advanced person's training method".

Each of the eight points starts with the word "samma" (Sankst. "samyak") - "right", which in this case means "high-quality", "adequate", "effective", "useful" - in bringing about the good results.

- The **right view** (or useful philosophy) stands for one's perspective on life in general.

  The central point of the right view is that our life can get better (away from afflictions & difficulties and towards wisdom & peace) or worse (away from wisdom & peace and towards afflictions & difficulties) -- depending on the choices we make. The subsequent points build up on this basic idea.
- The **right intention** (or useful attitude) stands for one's attitude as one goes about life.

  Right intention is trying to improve things, not to harm or make things worse. It is a deeply constructive attitude, not a destructive attitude.
- The **right speech** (or useful speech) stands for one's skill in interacting with others.

  Basically, it is speech of a wise person who knows what to say, how to say, and when to say it in order to achieve well-being for oneself and others.
- The **right action** (or useful behavior) stands for one's self-control in acting strategically and not impulsively.

  As with the rest of the points, the idea of right action is to not do anything (stupid) that will have an adverse effect, but to act skilfully in order to maximize the net benefit, esp. long term. The useful behavior is characterized by sobriety, discipline, moderation, and making wise choices about what one is getting into and with what kind of people one is connecting one's destiny. The useful behavior comes from the thought like "what kind of long term result will I get if I do this?"
- The **right livelihood** (or useful lifestyle) stands for the circumstances and environment one chooses or agrees to live in.

  Useful lifestyle is a lifestyle more or less supportive of the useful thoughts and useful actions towards a good result -- not a lifestyle that forces one to go in a completely opposite direction.
- The **right effort** (or useful effort) stands for self-improvement.

  Specifically, it means the ongoing effort to stop and get rid of the pathological habits/impulses/hangups, and to develop the "right" (useful) skills.
- The **right mindfulness** (or useful frame-of-reference) stands for watching for *the two kinds of thoughts* as one goes around the day.

  The idea is to not let oneself be carried away by the pathological currents, but to go around one's day while staying within the perspective of *arya marga*.
- The **right concentration** (or useful mood) stands for one's ability to control one's attention and therefore one's perspective and mood.

  The point of right concentration is to stop being the slave of information and to become the master of mind.

In short, in our day to day practice we must have a good sense of direction -- which way is feeding our ego and weaknesses, and which way is being an "arya" (advanced person). Your know your efforts are correct if you become less frustrated and more successful with whatever you do.

Because Sat-Dharma is "good in the beginning, good in the middle and good in the end", the Noble Path works on all levels:

- **On the mundane level** it helps one achieve success and better quality of life through developing self-control and discernment for constructive strategic action.
- **On the personal level**, it guides one towards overcoming neuroses, attaining the mastery over one's emotions, and achieving a stable & happy state of mind.
- **On the social level**, its emphasis on overcoming the harmful impulses, developing self-control, and the focus on constructive positive action - encourages cooperation, harmony, and seeking a compromise for the greater good.
- **On the intellectual level**, it encourages intellectual agility, open-mindedness, and anti-dogmatism as necessary conditions for skillful response.
- **On the level of the spiritual quest**, it provides a working framework and a practical way of gauging one's progress for abandoning obstacles on the way to Enlightenment - from overcoming coarse emotions, to dismantling the ego, to uprooting the preconceptions, to realizing the nature of mind, to attaining prajna-paramita.

Comment: Can you clarify 'slave of information'?

Comment: According to my teachers, it means you allow the information to drive you. One simple example is random information we get exposed to throughout the day. As it enters your system it makes you think certain thoughts that may lead to certain impulses, behavior, results etc. Instead, to be the master of mind means to decide what information to pay attention to _and how to interpret it_ - you play the active role in controlling what you focus on, how you assemble that into a coherent picture of the world, what that picture looks like, and how it affects your condition.